# Index of certain subgroups of the unit group of a quaternion division algebra over a local non-archimedean field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $F$ be a local non-archimedean field, let $F^\times$ be its group of units, let $\mathfrak{O}_F$ be its integers, let $\mathfrak{p}_F$ be the unique maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{O}_F$, let $\varpi_F$ be the prime element that generates $\mathfrak{p}_F$, let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the residue field $\mathfrak{O}_F / \mathfrak{p}_F$, and assume $2$ does not divide $q$.  Let $U_F ^n$ denote the subgroup $1+\mathfrak{p}_F^n$ of $F^\times$ for $n \geq 1$, and let $U_F^0$ denote $\mathfrak{O}_F^\times$, the group of units of $\mathfrak{O}_F$.

Let $E_r$ be a (tamely) ramified quadratic extension of $F$, and let $E_u$ be an unramified quadratic extension of $F$.  Let $D$ be a quaternion division algebra over $F$.  The notation in the previous paragraph carries over in an obvious way to the settings of $E_r$, $E_u$, and $D$.

If my understanding is correct,

- $F^\times \cong \mathbb{Z} \times U_F^0 \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{F}_q^\times \times U_F^1 $
- $E_u^\times \cong \mathbb{Z} \times U_{E_u}^0 \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{F}_{q^2}^\times \times U_{E_u}^1 $, and $\varpi_F \mathfrak{O}_{E_u} = \varpi_{E_u} \mathfrak{O}_{E_u}$
- $E_r^\times \cong \mathbb{Z} \times U_{E_r}^0 \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{F}_{q}^\times \times U_{E_r}^1 $, and $\varpi_F \mathfrak{O}_{E_r} = \varpi_{E_r}^2 \mathfrak{O}_{E_r}$
- $D$ is noncommutative, generated over $F$ by $\alpha$ and $\pi$, where $F[\alpha]$ is unramified and $F[\pi]$ is ramified; the set consisting of 0 and the powers of $\alpha$ is a complete set of residues for $\mathfrak{O}_D / \mathfrak{p}_D = \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$; $\pi$ is a prime element of $D$ (so sticking with the aforementioned notation, we could denote it $\varpi_D$), which satisfies $\pi^2 \mathfrak{O}_D = \varpi_F \mathfrak{O}_D$; and $E_r$ and $E_u$ embed in $D$.

**Question:**

> How can we calculate the the indices $\left[ D^\times : E_u^\times U_D^0 \right]$ and $\left[ D^\times : E_r^\times U_D^1 \right]$?

I suspect that $\left[ D^\times : E_u^\times U_D^0 \right]$ should be $2$, the same as $\left[ D^\times : F^\times U_D^0 \right]$; and I don't know about $\left[ D^\times : E_r^\times U_D^1 \right]$ -- maybe $q+1$?  (Those guesses are based on some computations I saw in a paper by Corwin, Moy, and Sally involving division algebras of higher dimensions.)  **It seems like it should be possible to compute these indices somehow using homomorphisms arising from the valuation on $D$, the reduced norm, and the reduced trace, but I don't know how.**  Admittedly, I need to do more exercises involving quaternion division algebras over local fields to get a better grasp of the situation... In the meantime, any hints or solutions would be much appreciated!

Comment: To construct $D$. You take two quadratic elements and you say $\alpha \pi = - \pi \alpha$, so  $\varpi_{E_u} \varpi_{E_r }=-\varpi_{E_u} \varpi_{E_r }$ ? You can write elements of $D$ as matrices $4 \times 4$ with coefficients in $F$